# Does bipolar encoding need a clock

Tags: ethernet, data

if it does then  when will a clock be useful in decoding bipolar signals

'I was thinking' it just see if it detects a      -voltage & a +voltage and do  "save " the bits accordingly

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

*All* serial signals require some kind of clock - either in a separate channel or (more commonly) embedded into the signal.

The basic problem is that the receiver loses track of the transmitter's symbol stepping when there are too many identical symbols in sequence (=the line doesn't change at all for a while). Whether you use electrical, single-ended, differential, optical or wireless signaling doesn't matter.

E.g. when the sender transmits ten zeros `0000000000`, the receiver may read that back as nine zeros or eleven zeros. The actual number of bits after which a resynchronization is required varies with PLL technology, but it's finite.

A simple *COM* link commonly sends a fixed `0` in front of (*start bit*) and a fixed `1` after each user byte (*stop bit*).

Early Ethernet uses Manchester code which runs a clock at twice the data rate and modulates it with the user data. Fast and Gigabit Ethernet use 4b/5b and 8b/10b respectively which ensure resynchronization after 5 bits at most. 10G Ethernet uses 64b/66b, forcing resync after 66 bits.

Comment: is it possible that it just see if it goes from0 to 1v and it write bit 1 and 0to -1 and write bit0  so no matter what time lenght and bit period ,isn't that sufficient @Zac67

Comment: You need to be able to track any number of same 0 or 1 bits - not possible without *any* clock.

Comment: but the 'tracking 'is in the pc with some electronics ,;just it's going to account bit 1 for  a positive voltage and bit 0 for a negative even if they are little distance a part ,and to end signal voltage 0 ,in ethernet wires ,10 base it's like that but they maybe talk about clock                        idon't see the use                                            https://youtu.be/i8CmibhvZ0c?t=363     "i preset the time in video it shows"

Comment: Yes, the *some electronics* requires some clocking to distinguish 10 or 11 zero bits (or one bits). More sophisticated electronics requires less clocking (100 or 101 one bits?) but still. 10BASE-T uses [Manchester code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) for clock recovery with *two* levels per user bit - `-+` for 1 or `+-` for 0. Simple but wasteful.

Comment: so a clock is used whitout "need" ; but is it technically what i said possible,;

Comment: No, there is need as I've tried to point out. You cannot send data without any clocking.